# Use PHP cURL to open result in new window

Tags: php, curl

I've a PHP form that uses cURL to access a third party application. I've also got my own validation on the form. Currently when you fire the form it is sent to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` and if there's an issue, the validation errors appear at the top of the form. If there's no issue, the variables are sent to the third party app and the browser takes the user to that app to continue the process.

Now, the client wants this form to open in a new window. I've added target=_blank to the form element, but this causes a new window to open even when the form is invalid (i.e. there are validation errors). So I need the form to stay where it is until it is actually submitted to the third party app.

Anyone know if there's a cURL variable that does a redirect to a new window? I can't seem to find anything in the manual.

Comment: By the way, I'm fully aware that this is HORRENDOUS ux practice, but  I give up with this client. I can't tell them otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing server-side and client-side code.

- cURL is *server-side*. When cURL is triggered (within PHP), your form has already been posted, it's too late to act on the client side.
- Javascript, however, is a *client-side* scripting language. You can use it to validate a form.

A good practice in modern web applications, is to pre-validate a form using Javascript, then post to the PHP script only if the form is validated. If you need server-side features to validate your form, then you might post some data and request information from the server with [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) first. There are some very good libraries such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) which make that painless nowadays (even posting the whole form with Ajax without leaving the page).

An old alternative would have been to post to the PHP script, validate the form, then output some Javascript tag to open a new window if the form is valid. However, this would now be blocked by any browser built-in popup blocker.

Comment: Ok, I'm very familiar with jQuery and Ajax, thanks. As this system is already built and working, I was hoping I could add a header to the cURL options (or something) that would force the response into a new window. But I see what you're saying, thanks a mill.