# how to open curl request in another window

Tags: php, curl

Hi i need to send a curl request from my web app to an external webpage

actually i use this code

```
 public function execute()
 {
$this->_prepare();

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->get_url());        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT           5.1; pl; rv:1.9) Gecko/2008052906 Firefox/3.0");
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);      
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $this->get_post_request_array());

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
 }
```

But this return a page with some js issues, so i need to open the destination webpage into  a new window. 
It's possibile do that with curl or i need to use another execute function?

thanks

Comment: Define "another window". From the current code, you're not outputting anything at all.

Comment: Here is the answer, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008385/use-php-curl-to-open-result-in-new-window